# How does one export classmethods to a module as module methods in a dynamic fashion in python?

Tags: python, oop, functional-programming

Assuming `python3.10`, suppose I have a class in some file:

```
class Foo(metaclass=ABCMeta):
  @classmethod
  @abstractmethod
  def do_fn(cls, yada, yada_):
    pass

  @classmethod
  @abstractmethod
  def that_fn(cls, this, that):
    pass


SpecializedFoo(Foo):

  @classmethod
  def do_fn(cls, yada, yada_):
    logger.info("doing it")

  @classmethod
  def that_fn(cls, this, that):
    logger.info("this or that")
```

And a system interface module that expects `do_fn` and `that_fn`:

```
# interface.py
from functools import partial

from specialized_foo import SpecializedFoo

##### A Foo Interface #####
# Optionally leverage the system integration
# Read the docs: https://yankee.doodle.etc/callbacks

do_fn = partial(SpecializedFoo.do_fn)
that_fn = partial(SpecializedFoo.that_fn)

### Done: Foo Interface
```

Is there a clean or at least automatic and **stable** way I can define a method in `SpecializedFoo` or abstract parent class `Foo` such that the system interface `interface.py` can simply call:

```
SpecializedFoo.export_interface()
```

And the method functions will be exported to the module's list of available module methods as if they were defined in the exact same fashion, e.g.:

```
do_fn = partial(SpecializedFoo.do_fn)
that_fn = partial(SpecializedFoo.that_fn)
```

Comment: I don't think `partial` is doing anything here, it could just as well be `do_fn = SpecializedFoo.do_fn`. I guess I would also question whether implementing as classes is adding any value (if you don't instantiate the class then a module and a class provide very similar level of abstraction)

Comment: @Anentropic partial is something I picked up from `enum` interop.  If I want to define an enum with a function member, partial is necessary.  So my gut is that partial is a better function reference for this purpose than simply assigning it, since it renders it more modular and value-like.  Although in the past I would have just assigned it.

Comment: @Anentropic implementation as classes adds encapsulation, mobility, a name, regions for comments, opportunities to add more variety to the code -- it is easy to move, easy to auto-refactor, easy to collapse, and self implementing via abstract method implementation.  There is also opportunity for compositional details that would not be maintainable in a module form. Whereas a heap of functions in a module is just that: an un-cohesive heap of functions in a module.

Comment: _"If I want to define an enum with a function member, partial is necessary."_ ...this is to prevent it from being understood as a method, so is specific to the context of something defined within a class body... i.e. not relevant to aliasing of classmethods as module attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer involves a small function added to the parent class:

```
class Foo(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @classmethod
    def export_interface(cls, module_name: str):
        module = sys.modules[module_name]

        # this can be handled dynamically by matching the `_fn` w/ re
        module.do_fn = cls.do_fn
        module.that_fn = cls.that_fn
```

And a single call in the `interface.py`:

```
SpecializedFoo.export_interface(__name__)
```

The user is responsible for avoiding collisions in the `interface.py`, but a system interface constructed this way (using modules as if they are classes) that imposes those kind of duties on the developer anyhow.